# Deep copying cv::Mat alternatives, which is better?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to deep copy an image. Which is better for performance?

```
cv::Mat new_img(old_img, true);
```

(this first one is not entirely correct, check my answer)
or

```
cv::Mat new_img = old_img.clone();
```

(Im asking it because the second one is more appealing for me in terms of being to the point, but Im not sure how much worse off I am. Maybe I would even define a constant `CV_CLONE = true`... in case the first one is better.)

Comment: Have you tried doing a benchmark? Usually declaring and defining in the same line is something compilers optimize

Comment: Hmm not yet. I was reading an other question and I just came know about the deep-copy constructor. I was kind of hoping for a quick answer from the experts I saw here around. :) But I'll do a survey on my computer on various sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see exactly what each does by looking at the [source code](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~eguillou/documentation/opencv2/mat_8hpp_source.html). The constructor is 00172, clone is 00346.  Both call the same internal function copyTo so I would imagine they are essentially the same in terms of performance.

Comment: hm. I understand that `copyTo` is the heavy operation here. On the other hand, does not the second one do a default construction first, then the cloning makes a new image, on which two even some ref-counting would be done up and down...? Could it make a difference for small images say 10x10? Or now it is just about splitting the atoms, there too?

Comment: ah, and thx for the codebase! I was looking for sth like that  yesterday.

Comment: You are right, more does appear to be happening in the constructor.  I don't know the specifics of the differences between the two but I would be very surprised if you can find a measurable difference.  Feel free to test it (I would just start with a 1x1), and if you find one please post it.

Comment: I've just heard about [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). It renders the `Mat.clone()` the proper way by any means. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have started to benchmark and... Hang on! There is no such thing as

```
cv::Mat(const cv::Mat& from, bool deep_copy=false);
```

What Hammer and I saw was:

```
cv::Mat(const CvMat* from, bool deep_copy=false);
```

curious...

So the correct solution would be

```
CvMat temp = img;   
cv::Mat img_clone = cv::Mat(&temp, true);  
// vs  
img_clone = img.clone();
```

and after profiling on small images: no difference as Hammer said. The reason they do not have cloning copyCtor is return value optimization (see wikipedia).

Comment: You are right, I pointed you to the wrong spot, the actual constructor is at 00109, i updated the answer to reflect that, sorry

Comment: Don't, your answer was great, my question was wrong ;) and the copy constructor is shallow, there's no deep-copy ctor.

Comment: You are right again!  I can't seem to read those things carefully

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. RVO is exactly the reason why `cv::Mat` _could_ have a proper, deep copy constructor, without giving up efficiency, right? Anyway, most OpenCV functions don't return matrices, but require you to pass a reference to an output matrix, so it's moot in most cases. Also, in C++11, move constructors can be added to handle the cases where RVO doesn't cut it. Inconclusive discussion on the OpenCV mailing list: http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Mat-copy-constructor-td6241953.html

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I no longer know enough about this subject so I could answer.